# jQuery clone data from h1 and append to an input box

Tags: jquery, clone

I'm trying to get the contents from a header tag and put it into a an input box.

My code sort of works but I can't get the data into the input box - can anyone help please?

```
$(".myDiv h1:first").clone(true, true).contents().appendTo(".inputClass");

<h1>this is my data</h1>
<input value="" />
```

Comment: Link the whole code including your HTML (with optional CSS) one please.

Comment: What's "data", and when you say input box, are you talking about an actual `input` element?

Comment: Yes an actual input element

 <h1>this is my data</h1>
 <input value="" />

Comment: Var txt = $(".myDiv h1:first").text(); $(".inputClass").val(txt);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to clone the element

just try to do this:

```
$(".inputClass").val($(".myDiv h1:first").text());
```

Comment: $(".inputClass").val($(".myDiv h1:first").text());

Comment: jQuery.html() treats the string as HTML, jQuery.text() treats the content as text